# Why are random values shown as output to find determinant of a matrix?

Tags: c

I wanted to find determinant of a M*M matrix by using **recursion** in **C**. 
Here is the code I have tried in Ubuntu.

```
// Computing determinant of a MXM matrix

#include <stdio.h>

int determinant(int M, int A[10][10]) { //Function to calculate det(A)
    int i, j, k, m, n, p, q, pow = 1;
    int B[10][10];//assuming M does not cross 10
    if (M == 1)
        return A[0][0];
    else {
        det = 0;
        for (k = 0; k < M; k += 1) {
            m = 0;
            n = 0; //m,n are indices of subdeterminant of A
            for (i = 0; i < M; i += 1) {
                for (j = 0; j < M; j += 1) {
                    if (i != 0 && j != k) {
                        B[m][n] = A[i][j];  //finding submatrix
                        if (n < (k - 2))
                            n += 1;
                        else {
                            n = 0;
                            m += 1;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            det += pow * (A[0][k] * determinant(M - 1, B));
            pow = -1 * pow;
        }
        return det;
    }
}

int main() {
    int M, i, j;        // M is order of matrix A for which determinant has to be found
    printf("Enter the order of matrix: ");
    scanf("%d", &M);
    int A[10][10];
    printf("Enter matrix A: ");
    for (i = 0; i < M; i += 1) {
        for (j = 0; j < M; j += 1) {
            scanf("%d", &A[i][j]);  //Entering elements of matrix A
        }
    }
    printf("Given matrix A is: \n");
    for (i = 0; i < M; i += 1) {
        for (j = 0; j < M; j += 1) {
            printf("%d ", A[i][j]); 
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    int det = determinant(M, A);
    printf("The determinant of given matrix is %d\n", det);
    return 0;
}
```

This code works fine for a matrix of order 2. But for higher orders, the output is some random number. I am unable to identify any mistake in this. Can anyone explain why the output is not as expected and how to rectify the code to get the expected output?

Comment: What values are you putting into your matrix?  How are you verifying that's the data that's actually *in* the matrix after you enter it, because your code does not check the return value from `scanf()` to make sure the data was actually entered properly. What output do you get?

Comment: Just a tip: if you only use the variable in the for-loop, write it as ````for (int x = 0, x < N, ++x)````, using the ````++````-operator, which is much more readable (to me at least).

Comment: Overflow quit possible - leads to UB.  Need to know the inputs.

Answer (score 2):

The inner loop that extracts the submatrix `B` from `A` seems broken.

Here is a simpler version:

```
        for (i = 1, m = 0; i < M; i++, m++) {
            for (j = 0, n = 0; j < k; j++, n++)
                B[m][n] = A[i][j];
            for (j = k + 1; j < M; j++, n++)
                B[m][n] = A[i][j];
        }
```